# Movings files NAS is slow, but from NAS to PC is fast

Tags: windows-7, networking, nas, speed, transfer

Somehow it only copies with 3mb per second when I try to move files from PC to my ReadyNas 516, but if I try to move files from ReadyNas 516 to PC, then it transfer with 80-100MB/s.

I'm using CAT 5E and CAT 6 cables in my whole setup. I'm using Windows 7, my network card is : Killer Network e2200. I don't understand why my system acts like this, because it has been working very fast with files transfer from my PC to my NAS before.

Any ideas?

---

My windows is installed on a SSD. But the file I'm trying to transfer is not in the SSD. I have just tried to make the copy through FTP protocol, which is extremely fast. Like 100MB/s. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: the answer is almost invariably related to your hard disks, and how they are connected to and operated by the NAS. Is it a RAID array? Is the disk connected to the NAS over USB? is the disk more than 90% used?  is the filesystem clean? does the NAS have sufficient free ram to buffer data before its written to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Something might be quick at reading, but slow at writing and vice versa.

From the sounds of things, I'm going to say it's most probable that your PC HDD has slow write speeds or it's I/O is being used by another process while your NAS is trying to write to it.

Assuming you're using windows - go to Task Manager > Performance > Resource Monitor. Then look at 'Disk'. This should give yo a better indication of what's occurring during the write from the NAS to HDD.

Comment: My windows is installed on a SSD. But the file I'm trying to transfer is not in the SSD. I have just tried to make the copy through FTP protocol, which is extremely fast. Like 100MB/s. It doesn't make sense.